# How to Serialize and Deserialize an observableCollection in Windows 8 Store App?

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm trying to serialize an ObservableCollection in a Win 8 Store App. I had already done this for a Windows Phone 8 App but I am a little lost on how to do it in Windows 8.

I know that the **IsolatedStorageFile** doesn't work in Windows 8. I'm using the **StorageFile** class to achieve it, however I'm not sure how to use it :-(

Here is the code on how I did it in a Windows Phone 8 App:

```
try
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<NewsByTag>));
    using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (isf.FileExists(sFileName))
           isf.DeleteFile(sFileName);

           using (var stream = isf.CreateFile(sFileName))
           {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, data);
                stream.Close();
           }
    }
}
```

... and this the one I'm trying to do in a Windows 8 Store App:

```
try
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<NewsByTag>));
    StorageFile sfFavourites = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(sFileName);


    using (StorageStreamTransaction sfFav = await sfFavourites.OpenTransactedWriteAsync())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(sessioinOutputStream.ToString(), data);
    }
}
```

Also, in the WP8 I was serializing to an XML file. But, for Windows 8 I'm don't know what would be the best. XML or JSON?

Does anyone have a good example how to do it?

Any help would be very appreacite ;-)

Regards!

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: En the second code at the moment to write the observablecollection. serializer.WriteObject(sessioinOutputStream.ToString(), data);
 an error saying that the beat overload for the writeobject method is incorrect

Comment: I used `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection);` for this. `JsonConverter` from Json.NET library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way -

```
MemoryStream sessionData = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer serializer = new 
            DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<NewsByTag>));
serializer.WriteObject(sessionData, data);


StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
                         .CreateFileAsync(sFileName);
using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    sessionData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await sessionData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    await fileStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Deserialize back this way -

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.
                           GetFileAsync(sFileName);
using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = 
            new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<NewsByTag>));
    var data = (ObservableCollection<NewsByTag>)serializer
                     .ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
}
```

Comment: Hi Rohit. Thanks for your help. I have tested your code and it works. The only thing that I'm facing now is that when the Observablecollection is written as an xml, when I try to deserialize it, it show me an error saying: There is an error in the xml document. I'm not sure if is the fact that the xml generated is all in an single line. Is well formated but in a single line.

Comment: By change, do you know how can I do the inverse process?

Comment: Updated with deserialized approach. Please check if that helps.

Comment: Thanks again Rohit. I tested the code and it works for me ;-)